# Verifying change of variable in published work

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, statistical-inference, change-of-variable

In the proof of Proposition A.11 on page 32 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.11038.pdf), the author takes the following step:

$$
\int_U \exp(-\|D_Gu\|^2_2/2 - \omega \|D u\|^2/2)du
=
\text{det}(I+\omega D_G^{-1} D^2 D_G^{-1})^{-1/2}
\int_U 
\exp(-\|D_G w\|^2_2/2 )dw
$$

which they explain is by substituting $(I+\omega D_G^{-1} D^2 D_G^{-1})^{1/2}u$ for $w$. To me this seems incorrect but given that it is central to the paper I am seeking a sanity check and likely missing something obvious. Note that the definition of $U$ is irrelevant to the question, $D_G, D$ are symmetric and positive definite matrices, and $\omega$ is some positive constant. Note that the exponent in the LHS can be written as

$$
-\|D_G u\|^2_2/2 - \omega \|D u\|^2/2 
= -\frac{1}{2}u^T (D_G^2+ \omega D^2)u
= -\frac{1}{2}\|(D_G^2 + \omega D^2)^{1/2} u\|^2_2,
$$
and plugging in the proposed subsitution: $u = (I+\omega D_G^{-1} D^2 D_G^{-1})^{-1/2}w$ gives
\begin{align*}
-\frac{1}{2}\|(D_G^2 + \omega D^2)^{1/2} u\|^2_2
&=
-\frac{1}{2}\|(D_G^2 + \omega D^2)^{1/2} (I+\omega D_G^{-1} D^2 D_G^{-1})^{-1/2} w\|^2_2\\
&=
-\frac{1}{2}\|D_G^{1/2}(I + \omega D_G^{-1}D^2D_G^{-1})^{1/2}D_G^{1/2} (I+\omega D_G^{-1} D^2 D_G^{-1})^{-1/2} w\|^2_2\\
&\neq 
-\frac{1}{2}\|D_G w\|^2_2.
\end{align*}

It seems to me that the correct substitution ought to have been: $D_G^{1/2}(I+\omega D_G^{-1} D^2 D_G^{-1})^{1/2} u=w$.

Comment: I have not yet read the paper but the equality holds if $$ (I + \omega D_G^{-1}D^2 D_G^{-1})^{1/2}D_G^{1/2} = D_G^{1/2}(I + \omega D_G^{-1}D^2 D_G^{-1})^{1/2} $$

Comment: Also, $$ (D_G^2 + \omega D^2)^{1/2}(I + \omega D_G^{-1}D^2 D_G^{-1})^{-1/2} = D_G^{1/2}(I + \omega D_G^{-1}D^2D_G^{-1})^{1/2}D_G^{1/2}(I + \omega D_G^{-1}D^2)D_G^{-1})^{-1/2} $$

Comment: @ThànhNguyễn thanks for the clarification - In the paper we take $D_G^2 = D^2+G^2$ where $G^2$ is a PD symmetric matrix. I guess I am not sure if the matrices in your first comment commute even with this additional information